# How can I fix the loose back power button on my Nook Simple Touch?

Tags: nook-simple-touch, hardware, ebook-readers, buttons

I have two NSTs, one with a GlowLight and one without, and they both have loose (they move slightly in their spaces) buttons on the back. Is there any way I can make those buttons fit tighter?

Comment: It would be nice to explain more about the problem, for example posting a photo. From your description it's relatively hard to find out what exactly the question is about.

Comment: Vote to keep open: This seems like a technical/physical question about a specific model of a ebook reader.  A photo while it might be helpful in the answer, should not be a requirement in the question. Any one with a similar device should be familiar with buttons on the back of the device.